# Minimum Required Framework for MVC 5.2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

What is the minimum required version of .NET Framework to run  ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3?
In https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6/ Microsoft noticed their updates for MVC 5.2.3. Besides, I see these properties in my VS2013 IDE:
[image]

Is the Runtime Version, is the required .net Framework Version to run MVC 5.2.3?

Comment: The Runtime is 4.0, and .NET 4, 4.5 and 4.6 all run on the .NET 4.0 runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum is 4.0.30319 because 4.0.30319 is 100% forwards compatible with all in place updates to the .Net framework that still have that version.